# My code is not execute without showing any error

Tags: python

As you can see I am trying to get sum of two numbers using sum function but it is not executed without showing any errors

```
 def sum(num1,num2):
    return num1+num2
    print(sum(56,74))
```

Comment: Please format your code properly; it is very unreadable right now.

Comment: What error do you get? Please [edit] your question to include it. And please show the code exactly as you have it. The extra characters prevent us from getting the same error that you get.

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum(num1,num2):

-------return num1+num2

print(sum(56,74))
```

you don't need any space before and after print
as you add space before print, it will treat 'print' in the sum function which will not call sum() function.

Answer (score 0):

Python can be very picky about what formatting it will accept, especially with spaces. Makes sure you copy and paste the exact code.

```
def sum(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

print(sum(56, 74))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling the function, you've to call outside the function. You're calling it inside itself which is called `recursion`. Call it in main program. Indent the print statement correctly. Your code:

```
def sum(num1,num2):
    return num1+num2
print(sum(56,74))
```

Output:

```
130
```